# Should i allow scrolling into whitespace?

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an android app. In one activity i have a Collapsing Toolbar which has:

- A title
- An image header
- 3 tabs

2 of the tabs contain scrollable data, and upon scrolling the toolbar collapses.

Now in the 3rd tab, there is only a few lines of data that the user is interested in (the rest is white space). If the toolbar isn't collapsed it looks pretty good. But my question is if 2 of the 3 tabs allow scrolling should i allow scrolling in this 3rd tab even though it would only increase the whitespace?

**EDIT**

Here are some screenshots of the tabs: [imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Kwm.jpg)

Note that the image header is currently empty. And all data is prototyping data.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you post a few screenshots?

Comment: Agree screenshots would help, could you just remove the whitespace?

Comment: Ok i edited the post and added a link to the screenshots (sorry they are so huge). thanks for your time guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you shouldn't.**

Scrolling is a mechanism required to reach certain areas of a layout that aren't visible on load. The presence of scrolling also transmits a clear [**affordance**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance): *there's more content to be seen*, which in your case isn't true. Thus, **adding scrolling would cause confusion and cognitive load**, making users look for something that doesn't exist.

**In short: do not add scrolling.** White/blank space is a given when a list is longer than other, and most users have seen this many many times. As a matter of fact, **a huge blank space after a list is an affordance itself**: *there's nothing else to see*. You'll notice this is the **exact opposite affordance** to scrolling, and this is what you're looking for.

Alternatively, if you feel this is a problem (for aesthetics or whatever) you could simply add an `end list` element, such as a line

Comment: ok i get exactly what you mean here but i have a follow up question. Say my user moves to the second tab and scrolls down, thus collapsing the toolbar. What if he/she decides to tap on the first tab while the toolbar is still collapsed? The white space that i tried to avoid would be there since the toolbar is collapsed, what should i do then?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, by clicking (well, tapping) on another tab, the user should go to the top of the new tab and your toolbar will get the appropriate behavior for that new instance (for example, toolbar collapsed or not collapsed)